# How to get `ListView` item to wrap_content starting from right side of the screen?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-custom-view

I have a `ListView` that has a custom adapter to provide a customized `View`. Each list item "changes" the side of the screen it is on (as if you flipped it around a vertical axis). Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

[image]

The darker gray boxes in the photo cover up a `ProfilePictureView` and a `TextView` containing a users name and photo. No name and photo if the user is not logged in (as you can see in the second list item in the photo). As you can see from the photo, the background image wraps around the content in the view for the first and third item (starting from the left and ending at the right).**The problem is:** the items facing the other way are ignoring my "wrap_content" call and are "matching" the parent view (as you can see in item two). I believe it is correctly wrapping the content but is there any way to start from the right of the screen and wrap content to the left?

Here's the `XML` code for that items view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right|center_vertical">

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="right" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <com.namespace.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            custom:typeface="roboto_light"/>

        <com.namespace.RobotoTextView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_user_score"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="36sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/waf_warm_yellow_orange"
            custom:typeface="roboto_bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView
            android:id="@+id/list_item_user_image"
            android:layout_width="69dp"
            android:layout_height="69dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

So, how can I align the view correctly to the right and have the background image correctly wrap around its content?

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate list item layout for left and right. In your adapter...

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position % 2;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int viewType = getItemViewType(position);
    int layoutRes = viewType == 0 ? R.layout.list_item_left : R.layout.list_item_right;

    View row = inflater.inflate(layoutRes);
    /* ... */
}
```

Basically, your adapter reports two different view types and your getView alternates between them. (If there's some other logic to determine left vs. right, implement it in `getItemViewType()`.)

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my problem was quite simple, inside my custom adapter I was setting the background image resource depending on whether it was an even or odd listview item. Instead of doing that I just had to make an imageview and set that image resource to the background image and set it to the correct side of the screen with the `android:layout_alignParentRight="true` and `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" attributes.